# What is wrong with my math?

Tags: mathematics

**Try to find the step where I made a mistake while proving that 1 = 2**

1. a = 1
2. b = 1
3. a = b
4. a^2 = ab
5. a^2 - b^2 = ab - b^2
6. (a + b)(a - b) = b(a - b)
7. a + b = b
8. 1 + 1 = 1
9. 2 = 1

Answer (score 6):

It is not correct at step 6 to 7, because you divide both of the side by (a - b) which is dividing by 0.

[Why can't you divide by zero?](https://www.google.co.id/amp/s/mathwithbaddrawings.com/2013/05/07/why-cant-you-divide-by-zero/amp/)